# Grouping items by relationships of their owners

Tags: algorithm

I have a set of data representing many sellers and the items they sell. There is an overlap between the various sellers' items. These items come from various distributors and typically an item comes from a unique distributor.

I am trying to come up with an algorithm that will group items by the distributors that sold them to the sellers. Any ideas come to mind?

Comment: Hello, welcome to AI.SE. Unfortunately, implementation questions are off topic you. You may want to try [datascience.se] or [stats.se].

Comment: Thanks a ton! Didn't realize that, appreciate the pointers.

Comment: What's your background with AI?  Are you also interested in high-level, general info on the types of AI methods that would be helpful in addressing this?  (i.e. there are several implementation-oriented Stacks related to AI.  It can be difficult for someone new to the field to identify which related Stack is appropriate.)  PS Welcome to AI!